# Is there a maven repository for flash-selenium.jar?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I recently moved to maven project and since then I found adding dependencies very difficult. Before that I just needed to download the jar and add to library folder .

 
Now I am searching flash-selenium.jar dependency but I failed to find any. So I added it manually in my C:.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\flash-selenium folder but still it is giving error. 
**So how can I use this jar in my maven project?**
Its a request to people those have 1500 points here , could you please create a label for selenium flash related problems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no flash-selenium dependency in maven central, but there are other artifacts like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
    <version>2.0rc2</version>
</dependency>
```

the complete list:
http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|selenium

Maybe some of this fits what you need.

Comment: I needed FlashObjectWebDriver.class which comes with selenium-server.jar . So the dependency you gave above, has this class?

Comment: Try this one 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.33.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Selenium server is already added but this doesn't have FlashObjectWebDriver.class

Comment: maybe it's time for some research ;)